# Calculate time passed and update all tasks

Tags: swift

I am creating a todo list app that counts down in seconds till the next task.

Once one tasks is complete the timer starts counting down till the next one and so on and so forth.

When the application is open this happens in real time, however when closed the timer is stopped and the current date and time are stored in a `NSUserDefaults` so they can be loaded upon opening.

When the application is opened I want to be able to do something simple like this:

```
let nextTaskIn   = 600.0 // example of were the last task was
let appClosed    = "2016-01-19 23:00:49 +0000" // example of time closed really comes from NSDate set on close
let timePassed   = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(appClosed) // get num of seconds changed
let nextTaskTime = nextTaskIn - timePassed // example 600.0 - 120.0 = 480 seconds left
```

Then I can update the text label to be the `nextTaskTime` all great!

However the issue comes when the time passed is longer than the current task and eats into the next task.

For example:

```
let task1 = 90.0
let task2 = 180.0
let task3 = 270.0
let timePassed = 110.0
let nexTaskTime = task1 - timePassed // this is not correct
```

This won't work, what it should do is make `task1 = 0.` and `task2 = 160.0` but recursively going thru all or as many tasks as there are till there are none left.

My best idea at doing this to get it to work was a while loop, but all I could come up with is a follows and I have run out of ideas.

```
let task1 = 90.0
let task2 = 180.0
let task3 = 270.0
var timePassed = 110.0

while timePassed > 0 {
    let takenAway = timePassed - task1 // but unsure how to swap out for next task if task = 0
    timePassed = takenAway
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this fit your question

```
let task1 = 90.0
let task2 = 180.0
let task3 = 270.0
var timePassed = 300.0
var tasks: [Double] = [task1, task2, task3] // init an array of your task

func updateTask(inout timePassed: Double) {
    for (index, _) in tasks.enumerate() { // enumerate your task
        let takenAway = timePassed - tasks[index]
        if takenAway <= 0 { // func should end here
            timePassed = 0
            tasks[index] = abs(takenAway)
            return
        }else { // keep going
            timePassed = takenAway
            tasks[index] = 0
        }
    }
}

updateTask(&timePassed)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this when I get home later but looks like a good possible fix.